# Python Edge Detection for measurement application

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image, edge-detection

I am new at Python and looking for edge detection on a single row or column. I want to make a mesaurement application and i have to detect edges in particular areas.

I tried 2 method. One of them is Sobel edge detection but probably it is not going to accurate.

Sobel method:

```
def findPoint(image,points,treshhold):
ROI=image[points[0]:points[1],points[2]:points[3]]
sobely = cv.Sobel(ROI,cv.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=3)
sobely *= 255.0 / np.max(sobely)                 
sobely[sobely<0]=0                               
sobely=cv.GaussianBlur(sobely,(3,3),sigmaX=1)
sobely=sobely>treshhold
cv.rectangle(img,(points[2],points[0]),(points[3],points[1]),(255,0,0),2)

labeled = measure.label(sobely)
regions = measure.regionprops(labeled)

for props in regions:
    row,col = props.centroid
    row=row+points[0]
    col=col+points[2]
    rowi=int(row)
    coli=int(col)
    cv.circle(img,(coli,rowi),3,(0,255,0),-1)
return row,col
img = cv.imread("Resimler/3.jpg",0)
points1=[405,430,355,360]
trh1=30
points2=[360,385,310,315]
trh2=30

row1,col1=findPoint(img,points1,trh1)
row2,col2=findPoint(img,points2,trh2)
dist=abs(col2-col1)
cv.putText(img,"{} px".format(dist),(220,300),cv.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,2,(255,0,0),3)
```

[trying to get kind of mesaurement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68Ud7.png)

My second attempt is subpixel_edges library.

```
from subpixel_edges import subpixel_edges    
img = cv2.imread("Resimler/3.jpg")
img=cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)

img_gray = (cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)).astype(float)
points1=[360,385,310,315]
ROI=img_gray[points1[0]:points1[1],points1[2]:points1[3]]

edges = subpixel_edges(ROI, 10, 1, 2)
print(edges.x,edges.y)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.quiver(edges.x+points1[2], edges.y+points1[0], edges.nx, -edges.ny, scale=30)
plt.show()
```

[Here is Subpixel Result(i wrote it in same pattern as sobel method). It looks way better but i dont have data to test repeatebility.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1UnJ.png)

Sorry for mess. Like i said i am new at python. Subpixel method looks fine but is it best method to make such gauging application? Any kind of suggestion for measurement application like i want to make will appreciate.

Comment: welcome to SE.Here we are not a general discussion forum. Your question is general and is asking for suggestions/advice, but here we give specific answers to specific questions. Can you please try asking a more specific focused question?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just detect edges in single row with subpixel accuracy.

Comment: "i dont have data to test repeatebility.": if you want to do serious measurements, a test set for repeatability is an ABSOLUTE MUST.